traefik-acme, Certificate resolver not found (traefik v2.4)
I try to use traefik-acme, a usefull go soft, available on  github to generate the certificates from the traefik acme.json
I am using Traefik v2.4 on Docker.
I want to do that to generate a secure mail server behind my Traefik proxy.
When I run the following:
docker run --rm  -v "/home/ubuntu/docker/traefik:/input"  -v "/docker/myservice/certs:/output"   --workdir /output ghcr.io/na4ma4/traefik-acme:latest --acme "/input/temp.json" mail.developpeur-web-france.fr

I have got the following error:

level=error msg="certificate resolver not found"

I thing that I don't use the right resolver, but this could be due to something else.
Here is my toml traefik file
[api]
    dashboard = true
    insecure = true

[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.web.http]
        [entryPoints.web.http.redirections]
            [entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint]
                to = "websecure"
                scheme = "https"
                permanent = true

[entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.websecure.http.tls]
        certResolver = "default"

[providers]
    [providers.docker]
        watch = true
        exposedByDefault = false
        network = "web"

[certificatesResolvers]
    [certificatesResolvers.default]
        [certificatesResolvers.default.acme]
            email = "edouard.touraille@gmail.com"
            storage = "acme.json"
            caServer = "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
        [certificatesResolvers.default.acme.tlsChallenge]

Could any one give me a solution to that problem? Or maybe give me the commands to build the software on a Ubuntu OS?

After looking a bit in the go code, I found that the certificate resolver should be the first key of the acme.json file, so it was "default" in my configution
Hence, a valid call to the docker container is
docker run --rm  -r "default" -v "/home/ubuntu/docker/traefik:/input"  -v "/docker/myservice/certs:/output"   --workdir /output ghcr.io/na4ma4/traefik-acme:latest --acme "/input/temp.json" mail.developpeur-web-france.fr

So, it generate well my private and public key.
